# Como puedo imprimir en pdf solo los resultados de una busqueda por fecha

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla ventas donde puedo buscar las diferentes ventas segun la fecha, ya tengo el buscar y el metodo de imprimir funcionando, pero al momento de imprimir , trae todos los registros de la tabla y solo necesito que imprima los registros de la busqueda realizada.

Este es mi index donde se realiza la busqueda por fecha.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //
    $hoy = Carbon::now();
    $fechaVenta = $request->get('fechaVenta');
    
    $registro = ventas::where('fecha', 'like', "%$fechaVenta%")->paginate(5);
    
    return view('ventas.index', compact ('registro'), ['row'=>$registro, 'fechaVenta'=>$fechaVenta]);
  
}
```

y este metodo es el que utilizo para realiuzar el pdf.

```
 public function imprimirVentas()
    {
        $rows=ventas::all();
        
        $pdf= PDF::loadView('pdf.ventas',['rows'=>$rows]);
        return $pdf->stream('listado-dados-'.date('Ymd').'.pdf');
    }
```

Tal vez estoy atorada en algo muy facil, pero soy nueva utilizando laravel y e intentado varias cosas.

Answer (score 0):

En la función `imprimirVentas()` estás llamando a la función `all()` del modelo `ventas`, la cual básicamente te trae TODOS los registros que tengas en tu tabla "ventas" sin importar la fecha ni nada. Tendría que ser como en la función `index()` (la primera que muestras), que ahí obtienes las ventas según la fecha que se ingresa y se las asignas a la variable `registro`.

Algo para corregir además: los modelos, en este caso "ventas", por lo general se escriben en singular y comenzando con mayúscula. Suerte!